# Push segue transition animation is somewhat choppy

Tags: ios, swift

I am using push segue with default animation for transitions on the navigation controller. However, the animation seems to be somewhat choppy. While pushing a new view controller, source view controller shifts left and hangs halfway through. And a moment after this, destination view controller appears.

Could you please help me to get rid of this?

Note: Application's content is retrieved from our API. But all network operations are done asynchronously on a different thread in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 2):

> But all network operations are done asynchronously on a different thread in viewDidAppear.

Nevertheless, any time you get this sort of delay, you should suspect a threading problem. And it sounds like that's what this might be.

Your first step should be to make a small project that simply does a push segue, to convince yourself that this choppiness is not normal. That way, you know that *you* are delaying the transition in some way. You can then proceed to think about what you're doing during the transition that might explain this.

Instruments can also be a big help here! Run Instruments to get a time profile, do the transition forward and back several times, and see where the time is being spent.

Finally, a word of advice. I've got an app where I do a push transition but it's going to take time for the content to be gathered. I supply placeholder content up front so that the transition can be performed immediately. Then when the transition is over I do my time-consuming gathering of information, and reload the data.