# Push segue transition animation is choppy

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

[Push segue transition animation is somewhat choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683269/push-segue-transition-animation-is-somewhat-choppy)
<- The explanation of the issue in that post states my issue exactly:

"I am using push segue with default animation for transitions on the navigation controller. However, the animation seems to be somewhat choppy. While pushing a new view controller, source view controller shifts left and hangs halfway through. And a moment after this, destination view controller appears."

The storyboard I have is almost like this...

[image]

...with the following exception: my master view is a UIViewController consisting of 2 container views, both containing UITableViewControllers, both dynamic tables. Selection from one of the tables pushes the detail view onto the stack (same as the storyboard example above). That push is the "choppy" animation

Like the OP's issue, the master view is shifting left behind the semi-transparent detail view that is shifting into view from the right side of the screen. When the detail view is fully in view, approx half of the master is still in view behind the detail view momentarily, and then it disappears.

All other transitions (push, pop, modals, dismisses, etc) are smooth. This applies only to devices that cannot display both of the split views at the same time, so no iPads.

Comment: What work do you do in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `prepareForSegue`?

Answer (score 2):

I also recently had this problem using a Master Detail storyboard with an embedded Navigation Controller. The choppy animation of the segue may have started when I changed the global tint but did not resolve when I changed to back. The issue was fixed when I changed the Background of the View of the Detail screen from Default to a different color. I found it did not make any difference which color as long as it was not Default.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your UI updates are in the main thread and if the code is already on the main queue then if you using `dispatch_async` may only going to have overhead. Especially in your `prepareForSegue` method or in the `viewWillAppear` there shouldn't be heavy pieces of code (that should stay in the background thread) in main thread that causing this kind of things.